# React Application Faces Routing Issues with BrowserRouter After Nginx Reverse Proxy Configuration

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, reverse-proxy

I have encountered an issue while developing a React application. I have set up a reverse proxy using Nginx, but my configuration utilizes BrowserRouter. This could be causing routing problems when using a reverse proxy, specifically when accessing 192.168.0.6:8060/books, everything works as expected. However, after implementing the reverse proxy, the address becomes http://180.168.131.5/s/8/0/168/192/G.http-8060/books, and the page fails to display correctly.

My Nginx configuration is as follows:

```
{
    listen      8060;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 2048M;

    location / {
        root  /wwwroot/frontend;
        index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

My React Router configuration is as follows:

<BrowserRouter basename={'/'}>

```
              <Route path="books" element={<Books />} />
              <Route path="books/:id" element={<Book />} />
  </Routes>
```

http://192.168.0.6:8060/books
and http://180.168.131.5/s/8/0/168/192/G.http-8060/books

both can working.